# Azure Durable Functions: Strange wait times between Fan Out/Fan In Operations

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I'm using Azure Durable functions with the Fan Out/Fan In pattern to scrape some websites - since there's ~60K pages scraped per day, I've opted to use with the Fan Out/Fan In pattern since using the normal function chaining takes at least 2-3 days to complete.

However, the function starts out fine, and decides at some point to stop executing the activity functions, and just hangs - despite having the running status as "Running." The point in which this happens varies, but is usually in the first 200-300 out of 60,000.

Though I have not deployed it yet to Azure and this happens in regular testing, I'm not sure what's the problem. I have not gotten errors with `axios` or the activity function itself - and debugging it does not yield any meanigfull information since it doesn't break inside the orchestrator nor the activity.

I'm suspecting it might be how I have structured my code, since it has a loop inside the call for running `Task.all`:

```js
// chunkedTasks: [[30000, 20000, ..., 42012], ..., [23012, ..., 23023]]
const chuckedTasks: number[][] = chunk<number>(data, 10);
for (const taskChunk of chunkedTasks){
    const tasksToRun = [];
    for (const task of taskChunk){
        tasksToRun.push(context.df.callActivity("scrapeWebsite", task))
    }
    yield context.df.Task.all(tasksToRun);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: One thing to try is divide the work to sub-orchestrators. Since each time a response arrives from an activity, it replays the orchestrator. A row gets added to history as well, which then grows by each response. By limiting the number of responses by using sub-orchestrators, you can get it to go a lot faster.